# separable equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how can i solve this as a separable equation?

$$p'-\frac1yp=-\frac1p$$

i tried to find integrating factor:

$$\eta  = e^{\int 1/ydy}$$
by this way which makes eta=y, but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p'-\frac py=-\frac1p$$
It's not a linear DE, integrating factor only works for linear DE.
$$p'p-\dfrac {p^2}y=-1$$
Substitute $p^2=u$ and $u'=2pp'$ then the DE becomes linear of first order. Then find an integrating factor.
$$yu'-2u=-2y$$
$$y^2u'-2yu=-2y^2$$
$$\dfrac {y^2u'-2yu}{y^4}=-\dfrac 2 {y^2}$$
$$\left(\dfrac {u}{y^2}\right)'=-\dfrac 2 {y^2}$$
Integrate and unsubstitute $u$.

Comment: i got $$\frac{{u}'}{2}-\frac{u}{y}=-1$$ here integrating factor is y, right?

Comment: Yes thats correct. I added some lines @Jane

Comment: Thankss a lott)

Comment: You're very welcome Jane @jane

Comment: @jane for the integrating factor method you need to put the DE on the classical form  $u'-2 \dfrac u y=-2$ then apply the method. Note also that your original equation is Bernoulli's differential equation check the wiki page.